# Android GPS Location Update Method does not work in OnCreate of Map activity

Tags: android, android-location

I am facing a problem with the `LocationManager` class:

I want to update my current location in `onCreate()` of a class extended from `MapActivity`:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
MyLocationListener lcs = new MyLocationListener();       
lcs.onLocationChanged(lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER));
```

whereas `getLastKnownLocation()` returns the location but inaccurate, I want to call `LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates()` which returns `null` in `onCreate()`:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
MyLocationListener lcs=new MyLocationListener();         
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, lcs);
```

Can anyone tell me how I will be able to get my current location in my `onCreate()`?

Answer (score 1):

`LocationManager` only communicates with your code using the supplied listener. When a new location fix is available, [`onLocationChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html#onLocationChanged%28android.location.Location%29) will be called in the `lcs` instance of the `MyLocationListener` class your created.

You don't want to risk your app being force closed while waiting for the first location fix in `onCreate()`.

Best practice is to register your `LocationListener` in `onResume()` and also **unregister** it again in `onPause()` using [`LocationManager.removeUpdates(LocationListener)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#removeUpdates%28android.location.LocationListener%29). Your users will thank you for not draining their battery when your app isn't in the foreground :)

Comment: Also, `requestLocationUpdates()` returns nothing (`void`), not `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, guys for responding and giving very reasonable suggestion but unfortunatly these didnt worked for me.

I acheived my goal by implementing little time delay and every thing started working fine and my primary goal of getting location in Oncreate method is acheived. It came up with the understanding that OnCreate method called first and OnResume later if you want to get your current location with map randering then you will have to wait for map to be render first then call the location update code.

Answer (score 0):

here is the tutorial
http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/?s=GPS

or try this
http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/04/29/android-development-using-gps-to-get-current-location-2/