# Requesting Location updates in oncreate method

Tags: android, locationmanager, oncreate

I am trying to implement a location alarm kind of application.
But whenever my application opens. my current location shows as null.

Below is my code.

```
package com.hrupin;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HelloAndroidGpsActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener, LocationListener {


    private TextView setLat, setLong, destLat, destLong, currLat, currLong, tjd, fromhome, toward;
    private Button setmyLoc, setDest;

    private EditText editLat, editLong;

    private LocationManager orgManager;
    //private LocationListener orgListener;
    // private LocationListener destListener = new destListener();

    private boolean gps_enabled = false;
    private boolean network_enabled = false;

    private String bestProvider;


    double orginLongitude, orginLatitude, destLongtitude, destLatitude, currLatitude, currLongtitude;
    float firstLat, firstLang, secLat, secLang;
    Location destinationLocation = new Location("gps");
    Location originLocation = new Location("gps");
    Location currLocation = new Location("gps");

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        setLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.setLat);
        setLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.setLong);
        destLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.destLat);
        destLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.destLong);
        currLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currLat);
        currLong = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.currLong);
        tjd = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.setmeter);
        fromhome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.destmeter);
        toward = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.currmeter);

        setDest = (Button)findViewById(R.id.SetLocation);

        editLat = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editLat);
        editLong = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editLong);

        orgManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


        try {
            gps_enabled = orgManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.i("gps_enabled", ex.toString());
        }
        try {
            network_enabled = orgManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.i("network_enabled", ex.toString());
        }

        // don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
        if (!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(
                    HelloAndroidGpsActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Attention!");
            builder.setMessage("Sorry, location is not determined. Please enable location providers");
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                    HelloAndroidGpsActivity.this);
            builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel",
                    HelloAndroidGpsActivity.this);
            builder.create().show();
        }


        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        bestProvider = orgManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        orgManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 0, 0, this);
        Location location = orgManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

        if (location!=null){
            setLat.setText("Latitude:" + currLatitude);
            setLong.setText("Longitude:" + currLongtitude);
            originLocation.setLatitude(currLatitude);
            originLocation.setLongitude(currLongtitude);
        }
        //else Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error in GPS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        setDest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {


                destLat.setText("Lat:"+editLat.getText().toString().trim());
                destLong.setText("Long"+editLong.getText().toString().trim());

                destLatitude = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(editLat.getText().toString().trim()));
                destLongtitude = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(editLong.getText().toString().trim()));

                destinationLocation.setLatitude(destLatitude);
                destinationLocation.setLongitude(destLongtitude);

                float distance = originLocation.distanceTo(destinationLocation);
                tjd.setText(String.valueOf(distance/1000)+ " Kms ");

            }
        });
    }

    /** Register for the updates when Activity is in foreground */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        orgManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 60000, 1, this);
    }

    /** Stop the updates when Activity is paused */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        orgManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL) {
            setLat.setText("Sorry, location is not determined. To fix this please enable location providers");
        } else if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
            startActivity(new Intent(
                    android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (location != null) {
            // This needs to stop getting the location data and save the
            // battery power.
            //orgManager.removeUpdates(orgListener);

            currLatitude = location.getLatitude();
            currLongtitude = location.getLongitude();

            currLocation.setLatitude(currLatitude);
            currLocation.setLongitude(currLongtitude);

            currLat.setText(String.valueOf(currLatitude));
            currLong.setText(String.valueOf(currLongtitude));

            float fromhome = originLocation.distanceTo(currLocation);

            float toward = currLocation.distanceTo(destinationLocation);

            HelloAndroidGpsActivity.this.fromhome.setText(String.valueOf(fromhome/1000)+ " Kms ");
            HelloAndroidGpsActivity.this.toward.setText(String.valueOf(toward/1000) + " Kms ");

            if (toward/1000 <= 14 ){

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You are "+ toward/1000 + " Kms towards Destination ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }


    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

I know this kind of question has been million times. I have tried all methods which has been specified in answers. But i havent got any output. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call requestLocationUpdates on onCreate as it is redundant since your code  will call it on onResume. The flow is onCreate --> onStart --> onResume.

Comment: Then How?? Please Explain me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can remove the call on onCreate, the call on onResume is enough. When the activity starts onCreate is called first and onResume will also be called before you see the UI. Thus if you requestLocationUpdates on onCreate and then onResume again, you called that function twice. Just initialize the orgManager on onCreate and requestLocationUpdates on onResume. You do not have to call requestLocationUpdates to be able to call getLastKnownLocation.

Comment: But if do that. It provides me a null value boss.

Comment: You would get null also if the GPS has not returned any fix. You should change the currLatitude to location.getLatitude in the setLat.setText in your code.

Answer (score 0):

To get Current Location, this is working pretty fine with me check this out.

our Activity is like this

---

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private EditText showLocation;
private Button btnGetLocation;
private ProgressBar progress;

private LocationManager locManager;
private LocationListener locListener = new myLocationListener();

private boolean gps_enabled = false;
private boolean network_enabled = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    showLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtShowLoc);
    showLocation.setEnabled(false);

    progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    btnGetLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetLoc);
    btnGetLocation.setOnClickListener(this);

    locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    try{
        gps_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){            
    }
    try{
        network_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);           
    }
    catch(Exception ex){

    }       

    if (!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Attention!");
        builder.setMessage("Sorry, location is not determined. Please enable location providers");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", this);
        builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel", this);
        builder.create().show();
        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (gps_enabled) {
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
    }
    if (network_enabled) {
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
    }       
}

private class myLocationListener implements LocationListener{

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(location!=null){

            locManager.removeUpdates(locListener);

            String Speed = "Device Speed: " +location.getSpeed();
            String longitude = "Longitude: " +location.getLongitude();
            String latitude = "Latitude: " +location.getLatitude();
            String altitiude = "Altitiude: " + location.getAltitude();
            String accuracy = "Accuracy: " + location.getAccuracy();
            String time = "Time: " + location.getTime();

            String cityName=null;

            Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            //public List<Address> addresses= gcd.getFromLocation (double latitude1, double longitude1, int maxResults)


            List<Address> addresses;
            try {
                addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                if (addresses.size() > 0)
                    System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                cityName=addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            showLocation.setText("City Name: "+cityName+"\n"+Speed + "\n"+longitude + "\n" + latitude + "\n" + altitiude + "\n" + accuracy + "\n" + time);
            progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL){
        showLocation.setText("location is not getting due to location provider");

    }
    else if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE){
        startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));

    }
}}
```

---

and main.xml is

---

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="1">
<TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:text="My Location is:" android:textSize="25sp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
<EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_weight="0.24" android:lines="5" android:id="@+id/txtShowLoc">
    <requestFocus></requestFocus>
</EditText>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:gravity="center">
    <ProgressBar android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/progressBar"></ProgressBar>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center">
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Get Current Location" android:id="@+id/btnGetLoc"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

and my manifest file is

---

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="rdc.getCurrentLocaion"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

---

let me know if you get any trouble!!

Comment: Insted of keeping a button, try to keep those gps queries inside oncreate method. You ll got to know what i m sayin

Comment: OnCreate method called first and OnResume later if you want to get your current location with map randering and don't want to risk your app being force closed while waiting for the first location then you will have to wait for map to be render first then call the location update code.
     or you should check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556738/android-gps-location-update-method-does-not-work-in-oncreate-of-map-activity

Comment: Your solution keeps telling me I need to enable location providers, but my network location provider is enabled in the settings.

Comment: @Jules please! look into **OnClick** method for this line "if (!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) ".. here **i'm checking both Network & gps provider** else you will get pop up, so you should just update condition in if block is **&& to !!** .. then it should work just one provider also, let me know if need more info

Answer (score 0):

@Ramdhan Thanks for your code. But i corrected a mistake made in my code.

```
  Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        bestProvider = orgManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        orgManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 0, 0, this);
        Location location = orgManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

    if (location!=null){
        setLat.setText("Latitude:" + currLatitude);
        setLong.setText("Longitude:" + currLongtitude);
        originLocation.setLatitude(currLatitude);
        originLocation.setLongitude(currLongtitude);
    }
```

Cheanged code:

```
if (location != null) {
        setLat.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude());
        setLong.setText("Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());
        originLocation.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
        originLocation.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());
    }
```